# Blinking checkbox

Tags: html, css, checkbox

Good day ! 

There is a `checkbox`, styled by `label`. 

When you hover over the `checkbox` it blinks once, after its activation, too, blinks once, what's the problem ?

How to make it not blink?

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkID" name="checkID" value="false"/>
<label for="checkID" class="checkbox " onclick="anonymousCheckbox(event, this)"><span></span>anonymous</label>
```

CSS:

```
.checkbox {cursor: pointer}

.checkbox:before {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    content: '';
    float: left;
    background: url(/img/svg/check_box_before.svg);
    margin: 0 7px 0 0;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px
 }

.checkbox:hover:before {background-image: url(/img/svg/check_box_hover.svg)}

.checkbox.on:before {background-image: url(/img/svg/checkbox_before.svg)}

.checkbox.on:hover:before {background-image: url(/img/svg/checkbox_hover.svg)}
```

Comment: It's not a *blink*, it's a *wink*. It likes you! If you need any help, consider wrapping your code as a live snippet ([mcve]). Make sure the issue is reproduced in the snippet. Also state in clear what is the desired behavior.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu, sorry, put the wrong question, correct ! I don't want the checkbox blinked.

Comment: I'll be more specific. What you posted ***does not work*** and cannot be used to reproduce the behavior you describe, for multiple reasons: **1.** `anonymousCheckbox` is not undefined. **2.** the svgs have relative paths and (funny enough) are nowhere to be found on [so]. If you don't allow people to experience the issue, your chances of getting help are close to `null`.